# Class of nilpotency of semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups, holomorph

Let $G=N\rtimes H$ for some groups $N$ and $H$. Is it true that the nilpotency class of $G$ is at most maximum of nilpotency classes of $N$ and $H$, if it is known that both groups are nilpotent? And if not is it true, that the nilpotency class of $\mathrm{Hol}(K)$ is at least $n$, where $n$ is nilpotency class of $K$, where $K$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ are both nilpotent? I tried to check the last statement in SAGE and it holds for all the groups I checked by now.

Comment: In general $N$ and $H$ nilpotent does not imply that $G=N \rtimes H$ is nilpotent. And it is easy to find examples, such as $C_{2^n} \wr C_2$. in which $N$ and $H$ are both abelian and $G$ is nilpotent of arbitrarily high class

Comment: For your second question, let $K = C_2 \times C_{2^n}$ with $n>1$. Then ${\rm Aut}(K)$ (of order $2^{n+1}$) is nilpotent of class $2$, but ${\rm Hol}(K)$ is nilpotent of class $n$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm sorry, for the second one I meant that nilpotency class of $Hol(K)$ is AT LEAST n.

Comment: But that is clear because $K$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Hol}(K)$.